# Building XML API with Grape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby-on-rails-3, api, grape-api

I'm building a XML API with the help of the Grape gem. What is the best way to building XML for API actions? Since Grape isn't using standart rails controllers, i can't use `views/../xml.builder`. What did you suggest? Maybe there are some best practices for building xml api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sinece there are no any answers, i will answer my own question.
I ended up with modules where are i declare different kind of xml responses and include this modules into my Grape API. In API actions i just calling response methods from this modules. With this approach my code is clear and separated.

Comment: Hi @Mikhail Nikalyukin I am running in a similar problem. And used same approach where in modules  generate xml with builder. However when trying to return using Grape I get an ``cannot convert String to xml`` error. I make use of content_type :xml, "text/xml". Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: @PSR It was a while ago and we used old grape version, it wasn't parsing our xml correctly to, i made a few changes in the grape. Take a look at my commits in the xml_formatter branches https://github.com/dpsk/grape/branches maybe it will help you.

Comment: I have the same problem now and I'm using rabl to render xml but it's not as flexible as xml.builder by far... could you please explain your solution a little further?

Comment: @zapico with which part you have troubles exactly?

Comment: @zapico take a look https://gist.github.com/dpsk/d426fbbadefbc74959c4, it's a simple example on how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be sample. Just provide format to tell grape your default format

```
format :xml
content_type :xml, "text/xml"
```

Then add `.xml` to the end of request url.